# Show that if $B \subseteq C$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this?

> Show that if $B \subseteq C$, then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(C)$

let $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Then, $x \subseteq B$

This implies that $$\forall a \in x, a \in B$$

This further implies that $$\forall a \in x, a \in C$$

Therefore, $$x \subseteq C$$

This implies that $$x \in \mathcal{P}(C)$$

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Basically, your proof is the statement $(X \in \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow X \subseteq B \Rightarrow X \subseteq C \Leftrightarrow X \in \mathcal{P}(C)) \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(C)$ elaborated at the lower level. More specifically, all you need to prove is the transitivity of the $\subseteq$ relation.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is indeed correct! :)